# What does the asterisk do in col("*") in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In an example on this page, what is `col("*")`? I can't find any explanation.

Does the following codes mean creating a new Dataframe by selecting all (*) columns and a new "`new_gender`" column?

```
val df4 = df.select(col("*"), when(col("gender") === "M","Male")
      .when(col("gender") === "F","Female")
      .otherwise("Unknown").alias("new_gender"))
```

Comment: * means select everything.So col("*") :select all columns

Comment: it has even more meanings : `col("mycolumn.*")` unpacks a struct-column, `count("*")` counts all rows, regardless whether they are null or not, while `count(col("mycol"))` only counts when `mycol` is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given code, the result dataframe has all the columns and a new column `new_gender` based in the logic provided.

> col("*"): select all the column in the dataframe.

The following returns `True` :

```
df.select(col("*")).schema == df.schema
```

Comment: Is there any reference for *? I can't find it in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column.

Comment: @Tyler傲来国主: you can find it at this link: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Column.html

Answer (score 0):

`col(*)` selects all columns

In your example, it's retrieving all the columns, and creating a new one named new_gender with values Male, Female or Unknow dependending on the gender column

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+------+---+----------+
|gender|age|birthplace|
+------+---+----------+
|     M| 34|       USA|
|     F| 14|        UK|
|     M| 12|     Spain|
+------+---+----------+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------+---+----------+----------+
|gender|age|birthplace|new_gender|
+------+---+----------+----------+
|     M| 34|       USA|      Male|
|     F| 14|        UK|    Female|
|     M| 12|     Spain|      Male|
+------+---+----------+----------+
```